# Should I use a Dictionary with the element's Id as a key instead of a List?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ienumerable

I want to store a `IEnumerable` of some object that have an `Id`.

There will be a lot of cases where I will need to get from that `IEnumerable` some element with an `Id`. In this case, will it be faster to use a `Dictionary` where the `Key` is the `Id` comparing to using `FirtOrDefault` with a `List`?

Does this means that if I need to get an specific element with some `Id`, should I always use a `Dictionary`? What are the trade-off where since `Dictionary` also implements `IEnumerable` like `List`? Is there something with better performance than this?

The cases that I want to compare are:

`FooDictionary.TryGetValue(Id, out var element)` vs `BarList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id)`

## Edit:

I'm not using the `Id` as an index, actually, my `Id` is an `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Comment: It depends which object do you have or how are you going to store it with or without separated id

Comment: On the surface, I would say dictionaries would be faster. They're implemented as a hash table and the time to retrieve is almost O(1). Whereas linq is actually iterating in your other example

Comment: It hugely depends on number of items, type of your Id and hash function.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use case.  If you will be inserting elements in order (ie. your ids will correspond to indices), then I would recommend a List since although both accesses should run in constant time, a list index will almost always be faster then a hash table lookup.  However, if you will be inserting miscellaneous ids (eg. `1001`, `17786`, `234`), then a dictionary would be the ideal data structure because a constant time lookup will always be faster than linear search (runs in linear time - ie. what `.First` will do).

Note: If you are using ids as indexes then, you can simply check if the id is in the list, (`id < list.Count()`) before accessing it.  It will also be faster with LINQ since you won't need to access the keys first (as you would with a Dictionary).